# Errors trying to build a framework using old Swift toolchain

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcframework

I'm trying to create a distributable xcframework with module stability enabled.

To test if module stability is functioning correctly (using *Xcode 13.3*), I installed a old swift toolchain for xcode that I downloaded from Swift.org (*swift-5.1.3-RELEASE-osx.pkg*) to try and build my project using it and see if the generated framework can be used in a project that might be using a newer toolchain. However the build fails with a couple of errors, including from `NSBundle.h`, `NSURLSession.h` and one that went `Could not build module 'Foundation'`.

I tried creating a sample project with just one swift file and one simple function and tried to build it using the *Swift 5.1.3 toolchain* to see if code/ settings in my project is causing a issue. But that failed with the exact same error. Am I missing some settings or going about doing this the wrong way?
[image]

Comment: You attempted to create a Frankenstein, and you are NOT testing Xcode 13.3, if you are trying to use an old toolchain. It's also not something apple officially supports. So stick to whatever Xcode 13.3 installs

Comment: @ytrewq Module stability is something Apple supports, AFAIK. So, how does one go about testing module stability without using a different toolchain? Do I need to install different versions of XCode that has older toolchains? Any help is appreciated. BTW, Frankenstein's monster

Comment: Changing toolchain has nothing to do with module stability. Module stability is when you for example build one framework in Xcode 12.4, another in Xcode 13.0, and then can use them both in your project in Xcode 13.3. So if you want to test module stability, you need to compile module with earlier version of Xcode, and then use it in some project with Xcode 13.3

Comment: @ytrewq Oh, I was under the impression that the changing toolchains would have the same/ similar effect that of changing XCode versions, since each XCode version comes with it's own swift compiler version which I assumed was the significant cause for module incompatibility. I'm not very good with compilers/ toolchains, I'll take your advice on installing a older version on XCode instead of installing a old toolchain.

Comment: You can just download and install Xcode in parallel with the latest one - there's no problem with that. Here's a good guide: https://medium.com/a-swift-misadventure/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-xcode-on-the-same-macos-machine-a2836387e57f